# How to know used data by someone after enabling Wifi Hotspot?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, wifi-hotspot

My iVooMi Me5 Smartphone runs on Android 7.0.

I enable WiFi Hotspot frequently for some users.

I would like to know data usages by users based on day and date.

Please let me know, how to get it?

Regards

FewL

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent way to do this with stock Android that I have encountered.

According to this there is, or used to be in the past.  https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-measure-data-usage-from-a-wifi-hotspot, but I cannot find that in my android 7.0 phone.

There are apps on the play store that claim to track data more detailed, but I have not used them, or know how safe they are.